# VS 2015 WPF: Dictionary causes Window to freeze / Namespaces not created

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm toying arround a bit with the new VS 2015, and I found two strange behaviors, I really can't explain. Probably you can help me, if this are simple bugs or Im doing something generally wrong:
Í have a simple Project, the Mainwindow has just a Datagrid:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

In the App.XAML I load a Dictionary in a Subfolder:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionaries\AppDictionary.xaml" />
</Application.Resources>
```

The Dictionary is looking like this:

```
<Style TargetType="Grid">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
</Style>
```

Now, as soon as I load the Window, it seems to be frozen forever. I tested some Grid-Properties, but this happens only, when I set the Margin it seems.
I checked the Inheritance from DataGrid or DataGridTextColumn, but they don't seem to inherit from the Grid anyhow.

They second exception:
I need to create a Class in the Dictionaries-Subfolder, otherwise i keep getting the exception:

> The type or
>   namespace name 'Dictionaries' does not exist in the namespace
>   'WpfApplication3' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)

I didn't work with WPF for a while, but I'm almost certain, I didn't have such problems before, but I might be wrong on this case.

Edit: When I break the Debugging I get the Message:
"Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads where executing external code".

Comment: If you pause the running application you can view the call stack to see where the application is currently executing.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, see my edit, I can't see any code.

Answer (score 0):

Your information doesn't seem complete but It seems that you are not building the `Dictionaries\AppDictionary.xaml` file. You need to set its Build Action to Resource.

Also, your dictionary should look like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionaries\AppDictionary.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Wouldnt that mean the other Style-Setters would get ignored? And aren't MergedDictionaries only used, if I have more than one and want them, well, merged?

Comment: `ResourceDictionary` root with a source causes all kinds of issues in wpf apps. You should root MergedDictionaries for merging resource dictionaries.